# Form elements not being read by the controller method java ee sql

Tags: java, sql, jsp, servlets, jdbc

My form parameters are not loading data into the controller, I'm getting this message in the console:

```
INSERT INTO Products (code, cateogyr_code, product_category, product_name, description, price) VALUES ('0','0','null','null','null')'0.0')
```

The form is as follows:

```
    <form action="controller" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">
<table>
<tr><td>Code</td><td><input name="code"></td></tr> 
<tr><td>Name</td><td><input name="product_name"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Category Code</td><td><input name="category_code"></td></tr> 
<tr><td>Category</td><td><input name="product_category"></td></tr> 
<tr><td>Description</td><td><input name="description"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Price</td><td><input name="price" ></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save"></td></tr> </table> </form>
```

And this is my controller method:

```
  else if (action.equals("add")) {
            Product newProduct= new Product();

            dao.addProduct(newProduct);

              List<Product> products = dao.findAll();
              address = "listproduct.jsp";
              request.setAttribute("products", products);;
```

and this is my sql method

```
public void addProduct(Product product) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Products " +
            "(code, category_code, product_category, product_name, description, price)" +
            " VALUES (" +
            "'" + product.getCode() + "'," +
            "'" + product.getCategory_code() + "'," +
            "'" + product.getCategory() + "'," +
            "'" + product.getName() + "'," +
            "'" + product.getDescription() + "')"+
            "'" + product.getPrice() + "')";
    System.out.println(sql);
        }
```

Can someone please assist me with this?

Comment: Does the request reach the controller ? are the parameters passed correctly ? where does it fail ?

Comment: It is failing at the jsp page, the reqeust is definitely reaching the controller and the controllerImpl class, but the form parameters are not passed through ( they are all "null") as you can see in the error

Comment: "as you can see in the error" - well, I can't really see the error... :)

Comment: I meant the console message which shows the values assigned being 'null' and 0.

Comment: Try using a Firefox extension called tamperData when you submit the form to see exactly which parameters are submitted and to which URL.

Comment: SQL injection attack alert!! Start learning how to use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). It's by the way sad to see that no one of the commenters/answerers participating so far highlighted this major security hole.

Comment: After all, your question is unclear. Are you complaining about a syntactically invalid SQL statement, or are you complaining about the null/empty column values in the SQL statement? As to the latter I'm nowhere seeing you doing a `product.setXxx(request.getParameter("xxx"))`. How exactly are you filling the model values with submitted (and converted/validated) values? As to the strange "message in the console", please replace the silly `System.out.println(e.getMessage())` by `throw new ServletException(e)`. Then you'll get a fullworthy error page with stack trace and all on em.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the proper way of insertion

```
INSERT INTO Products (code, cateogyr_code, product_category, product_name, description, price) VALUES ('0','0','null','null','null')'0.0')
```

Assuming all fields are varchar use this way

```
INSERT INTO Products (code, cateogyr_code, product_category, product_name, description, price) VALUES ('0','0','null','null','null','0.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

First mistake is in your insert statement. Change it to as :

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Products " +
        "(code, category_code, product_category, product_name, description, price)" +
        " VALUES (" +
        "'" + product.getCode() + "'," +
        "'" + product.getCategory_code() + "'," +
        "'" + product.getCategory() + "'," +
        "'" + product.getName() + "'," +
        "'" + product.getDescription() + "'," +
        "'" + product.getPrice() + "')";
```

You are creating new object of product every time when you click on `add` button.

```
Product newProduct= new Product(); // This cause you a problem.
```

This `new Product()` statement create new object of product in which all values of variables are set to default. That means, the values of code = 0, cateogyr_code = 0, product_category = null, product_name = null, description = null, price = 0 are set.

The solution : Define a constructor with all parameters in Product class or find some other method to set the Product object in your arraylist.

Comment: I already have a Product calss with a constructor and getters and setters methods.

Comment: I added extra details in the question, my sql addProduct method, which I'm calling in the controller

Comment: @user2045298 : I corrected the syntax mistake of your query. Check my Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you write insert method in string data type, you should write single code "'\" like this instead of "'".